# ReactJS handleChange on every HTML input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am following the ReactJS tutorial on the official site and I am curious about a design choice. Basically the tutorial said we need to have a handleChange function on every input's onChange.

```
handleAuthorChange: function(e) {
    this.setState({author: e.target.value});
},

<input
    type="text"
    placeholder="Your name"
    value={this.state.author}
    onChange={this.handleAuthorChange}
/>
```

Does it mean if I have a form that has 10 text inputs and 3 checkbox inputs every single one of them needs to have a "handleChange" function?

What is the best practices of handling this situation?

Answer (score 2):

It is a recommended way to use `controlled components`, which is handling all the `inputs` with an `onChange()` handler. But, you don't need to handle the in a different handler for each, you can handle all the `onChange()` with on handler but, identify the target uniquely and set the value to the state.

See the fiddle for an example https://jsfiddle.net/Pranesh456/ga2csaty/4/

> In this example, I've used a common `onChange()` handler but I
>   uniquely identified each input box with their `id` and populated the
>   state based on the `id` which is been served as the `value` for the
>   input boxes.

For more reference check [React's controlled components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)

Comment: Yeah I figured there is an easier way by using a "general" function to handle all onChange callbacks but does your function takes into account checkbox/radio inputs too?

Comment: @StevenLee Yes. Anything with the id. But, for the checkbox the implementation should will be different.

Comment: @StevenLee Updated the fiddle with checkbox and radio buttons. Please check

Answer (score 0):

Not really, you can just remove `value={this.state.author}` and `onChange={this.handleAuthorChange}` from the code and it will still work. If you want to refer your input when you are submitting a form, I'd use `ref` feature in React. It is a way to create a reference to the input for later use.

```
handleAuthorChange: function(e) {
    this.setState({author: e.target.value});
},

<input
    type="text"
    placeholder="Your name"
    ref={(c) => this.yourNameField = c}
/>
```